# using mid function in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column that has data like this:

1. TEXT000612
2. TEXT721
3. TEXT8

Expected output:

1. 000612
2. 721
3. 8

The column only has a 4 letter text text and its only at the beginning at the cell. But the numbers can vary in length. Also, I want to make sure the numbers are string.

There is no mid function in BQ.

Also, if you dont like my question or think it needs to be improve please give me a chance to improve it before flagging it.

Answer (score 2):

Few options for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT col, 
  SUBSTR(col, 5),
  REGEXP_REPLACE(col, r'^TEXT', '')
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the numbers, use `substr()`:

```
substr(col, 5)
```

You can `cast()` this to a number if you want.